# Effective search from a huge number of points

Tags: java, android, graph

I have a bunch of gps points collected and now I need to make a match of these points with 18000 points. I have these in two arraylists. Is there a better way to search? I am performing this in Java.

Here is a sample of huge data. They contain one more additional parameter ID1 by which a set of points can be grouped.

```
ID1     ID2     ID3      longi          lati,
2   1   1   -79.911635  39.609849,
2   1   2   -79.91151   39.60956,
2   1   3   -79.9115    39.609489,
2   1   4   -79.911496  39.609433,
3   1   1   -79.908162  39.609841,
3   1   2   -79.908447  39.610019,
4   1   1   -79.911136  39.608433,
4   1   2   -79.910961  39.608446,
4   1   3   -79.910629  39.608451,
4   1   4   -79.910064  39.608493,
4   1   5   -79.909117  39.608586,
```

Comment: can you define what do you mean by "make a match of these points"?

Comment: also, are id1, id2, and id3 relevant in any way? Should they be matched too, or are you only looking at coordinates?

Comment: bpgergo: I will be collecting gps points from my mobile. As the gps points I get are not accurate I need to make matching with the existing standard set of points to make sure that they belong to a link(ID1). Its a way of standardizing the points I collect.

Comment: @tucuxi: ID1 defines a link ID. ID2 has nothing, ID3 defines the number of points in the link.

Comment: For now what I am doing is calculating the distance between the first point and all the set of standard points and then find a nearest matching point based on the least distance between them. Repeat this loop for all points collected. It's not an efficient way. So, I need some efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for exact matches, then you can place the points in a set (both HashSet and TreeSet will work), and find the intersection: `set1.intersect(set2)`. You will have to implement compare() or hashcode() accordingly, and equals() in any case, but that is the easy scenario.

If you are looking for "closer than X", you should use a [quadtree](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). Place all the nodes in the first arraylist in a quadtree, and then perform quick lookup using this datastructure (which can yield the closest point in O(log N) per lookup instead of the O(N) per lookup of the brute-force approach). There is an open-source implementation of a quadtree in, for example, [geotools](http://geotools.org/).

Comment: could you please give me an example on how to use this in quadtree?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the spatial index known as `RTREE`. It is usually faster than `quadtree`.

For example this paper finds it to be 2 -3 times faster in Oracle databases: http://pdf.aminer.org/000/300/406/incorporating_updates_in_domain_indexes_experiences_with_oracle_spatial_r.pdf

Java Topology Suite (JTS) contains a good implementation of the `rtree`: http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/index/strtree/STRtree.html

Note that `GeoTools` is based on JTS, so there may well also be an `rtree` lurking inside the spatial index functionality of it: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/main/collection.html